# code:which(riak_pb_client). non_existing

Tags: erlang, riak

In the Erlang shell it shows riak_pb_client as not existing when trying to test out the [erlang-riak-client](https://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client). I have listed the git source in deps, issued `rebar get-deps` and `rebar compile` which both complete successfully.

```
{deps,
  [
    {eredis, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/wooga/eredis.git", "HEAD"}},
    {jsx, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx.git", "HEAD"}},
    {riakc, "1.*.*", {git, "https://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client.git", "HEAD"}}
  ]
}.
```

I must be running the erl command incorrectly. Although, from the root of my project, I can see the library at deps/riakc, but `erl -pa ebin/ deps/*/ebin` is not loading the library (or perhaps just not with the name I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I believe that the correct module name is `riakc_pb_socket` and not `riak_pb_client`. The following should work:

```
code:which(riakc_pb_socket).
```